# css background image and img tag positioning

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to do like this 
a border in each li and a background color

if there is offer for product a image with offer value must come
else there is no offer the triangle image must not display.

[this is i want](http://demo.chromiumitsolutions.com/ruthcustom_cakes/home-cakes.png)

Like this i have 4 columns 
margin right and width - i wantr to give in em and %. CAn anyone tell how?
HTML:

```
<li class="home-latest-cakes" id="product-42">
                <a href="http://localhost:8083/vignesh/works/cakes/?product=sample-2">
                                            <div class="product-bg">                        




                    <img width="124" height="238" alt="product-1" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="http://localhost:8083/vignesh/works/cakes/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/product-1.png">                                                </div>
                </a>                    
            </li>
```

CSS:

```
.home-latest-cakes {
   border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
   color: #E4E4E4;
   float: left;
   height: 465px;
   margin-right: 1.6em;
       width: 200px;
}
.product-bg {
   background-color: #F8F9F4;
   height: auto;
   margin: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}
.offer {
   background: url("images/offer-bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   float: right;
   font-family: Impact;
   font-size: 30px;
   height: 92px;
   min-width: 94px;
   z-index: 999;
}
.percent {
   color: #FFF000;
   float: right;
   font: 30px "Impact";
}
ins.off {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: "Bebas";
   font-size: 20px;
   left: 60px;
   position: relative;
   top: 31px;   }
```

Answer (score 1):

That triangle should be separate image, you can place it with `position:absolute;` . It is because you cannot define conditions with pure html and doing it with Jquery or javascript would cause a blink.